# Spring boot TestRestTemplate doesn't URL decode requestparam values

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

Setup:

- Spring Boot + SpringBootApplication; Spring Boot Test + TestRestTemplate for testing
- 1 endpoint, processed by method foo.
- input: 1 required request param (named q) that must be URL-encoded in the URI.
- output: (foo) just returns the string (q). no processing done by foo.

If I start the server and curl the endpoint with the URL-encoded value, I get the non-URL-encoded value in the response.

If I query exactly the same thing with TestRestTemplate, foo gets a URL-encoded value to process and things start going wrong in the real world...

com.example.App

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class App {

    @RequestMapping(path = "/test")
    public String foo(@RequestParam("q") String val) {
        return val;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

com.example.TestApp

```
package com.example;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;

import java.net.URI;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class TestApp {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate rest;

    @Test
    public void testIt() {
        URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath("/test")
            .queryParam("q", BIG_STR)
            .build().encode().toUri();
        System.out.println("URI: " + uri);
        ResponseEntity<String> res = rest.getForEntity(uri, String.class);
        System.out.println("resBody: " + res.getBody());
    }

    private static String BIG_STR = "[ { \"_id\": \"58ac70a1d998ec63dc004158\", \"index\": 0, \"guid\": \"68124ce4-6a65-4459-8189-f245236399a9\", \"isActive\": true, \"balance\": \"$3,415.67\", \"picture\": \"http://placehold.it/32x32\", \"age\": 36, \"eyeColor\": \"brown\", \"name\": \"Bobbi Barr\", \"gender\": \"female\", \"company\": \"ACCUPHARM\", \"email\": \"bobbibarr@accupharm.com\", \"phone\": \"+1 (938) 592-3835\", \"address\": \"551 Lester Court, Sedley, South Carolina, 3698\", \"about\": \"Dolor deserunt nostrud ipsum sunt aute elit exercitation tempor eu ipsum. Dolor magna nisi incididunt sit non mollit ut aliqua. Magna est officia veniam sit deserunt eiusmod consectetur do dolore et ea aliquip. Magna velit tempor est dolore sint voluptate. Et enim cillum voluptate nisi est non. Non enim amet ad qui cillum ipsum ipsum magna id nostrud cillum amet esse.\\r\\n\", \"registered\": \"2014-08-05T12:07:38 +07:00\", \"latitude\": -79.673386, \"longitude\": -30.821609, \"tags\": [ \"aute\", \"consequat\", \"veniam\", \"exercitation\", \"quis\", \"proident\", \"mollit\" ], \"friends\": [ { \"id\": 0, \"name\": \"Carolina Barton\" }, { \"id\": 1, \"name\": \"Glover Gibbs\" }, { \"id\": 2, \"name\": \"Simpson Hicks\" } ], \"greeting\": \"Hello, Bobbi Barr! You have 2 unread messages.\", \"favoriteFruit\": \"banana\" } ]";
}
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '1.5.1.RELEASE'

  testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
  testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: '1.5.1.RELEASE'
}
```

Output of server start + curl:

```
curl -i "http://localhost:8080/test?q=%5B%20%7B%20%22_id%22:%20%2258ac70a1d998ec63dc004158%22,%20%22index%22:%200,%20%22guid%22:%20%2268124ce4-6a65-4459-8189-f245236399a9%22,%20%22isActive%22:%20true,%20%22balance%22:%20%22$3,415.67%22,%20%22picture%22:%20%22http://placehold.it/32x32%22,%20%22age%22:%2036,%20%22eyeColor%22:%20%22brown%22,%20%22name%22:%20%22Bobbi%20Barr%22,%20%22gender%22:%20%22female%22,%20%22company%22:%20%22ACCUPHARM%22,%20%22email%22:%20%22bobbibarr@accupharm.com%22,%20%22phone%22:%20%22%2B1%20(938)%20592-3835%22,%20%22address%22:%20%22551%20Lester%20Court,%20Sedley,%20South%20Carolina,%203698%22,%20%22about%22:%20%22Dolor%20deserunt%20nostrud%20ipsum%20sunt%20aute%20elit%20exercitation%20tempor%20eu%20ipsum.%20Dolor%20magna%20nisi%20incididunt%20sit%20non%20mollit%20ut%20aliqua.%20Magna%20est%20officia%20veniam%20sit%20deserunt%20eiusmod%20consectetur%20do%20dolore%20et%20ea%20aliquip.%20Magna%20velit%20tempor%20est%20dolore%20sint%20voluptate.%20Et%20enim%20cillum%20voluptate%20nisi%20est%20non.%20Non%20enim%20amet%20ad%20qui%20cillum%20ipsum%20ipsum%20magna%20id%20nostrud%20cillum%20amet%20esse.%5Cr%5Cn%22,%20%22registered%22:%20%222014-08-05T12:07:38%20%2B07:00%22,%20%22latitude%22:%20-79.673386,%20%22longitude%22:%20-30.821609,%20%22tags%22:%20%5B%20%22aute%22,%20%22consequat%22,%20%22veniam%22,%20%22exercitation%22,%20%22quis%22,%20%22proident%22,%20%22mollit%22%20%5D,%20%22friends%22:%20%5B%20%7B%20%22id%22:%200,%20%22name%22:%20%22Carolina%20Barton%22%20%7D,%20%7B%20%22id%22:%201,%20%22name%22:%20%22Glover%20Gibbs%22%20%7D,%20%7B%20%22id%22:%202,%20%22name%22:%20%22Simpson%20Hicks%22%20%7D%20%5D,%20%22greeting%22:%20%22Hello,%20Bobbi%20Barr20You%20have%202%20unread%20messages.%22,%20%22favoriteFruit%22:%20%22banana%22%20%7D%20%5D"
HTTP/1.1 200
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 1194
Date: Tue, 21 Feb 2017 17:19:26 GMT

[ { "_id": "58ac70a1d998ec63dc004158", "index": 0, "guid": "68124ce4-6a65-4459-8189-f245236399a9", "isActive": true, "balance": ",415.67", "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32", "age": 36, "eyeColor": "brown", "name": "Bobbi Barr", "gender": "female", "company": "ACCUPHARM", "email": "bobbibarr@accupharm.com", "phone": "+1 (938) 592-3835", "address": "551 Lester Court, Sedley, South Carolina, 3698", "about": "Dolor deserunt nostrud ipsum sunt aute elit exercitation tempor eu ipsum. Dolor magna nisi incididunt sit non mollit ut aliqua. Magna est officia veniam sit deserunt eiusmod consectetur do dolore et ea aliquip. Magna velit tempor est dolore sint voluptate. Et enim cillum voluptate nisi est non. Non enim amet ad qui cillum ipsum ipsum magna id nostrud cillum amet esse.\r\n", "registered": "2014-08-05T12:07:38 +07:00", "latitude": -79.673386, "longitude": -30.821609, "tags": [ "aute", "consequat", "veniam", "exercitation", "quis", "proident", "mollit" ], "friends": [ { "id": 0, "name": "Carolina Barton" }, { "id": 1, "name": "Glover Gibbs" }, { "id": 2, "name": "Simpson Hicks" } ], "greeting": "Hello, Bobbi Barr20You have 2 unread messages.", "favoriteFruit": "banana" } ]
```

Log output of integration test:

```
2017-02-21 09:28:17.912  INFO 51360 --- [           main] com.example.TestApp                      : Started TestApp in 2.016 seconds (JVM running for 2.598)
URI: /test?q=%5B%20%7B%20%22_id%22:%20%2258ac70a1d998ec63dc004158%22,%20%22index%22:%200,%20%22guid%22:%20%2268124ce4-6a65-4459-8189-f245236399a9%22,%20%22isActive%22:%20true,%20%22balance%22:%20%22$3,415.67%22,%20%22picture%22:%20%22http://placehold.it/32x32%22,%20%22age%22:%2036,%20%22eyeColor%22:%20%22brown%22,%20%22name%22:%20%22Bobbi%20Barr%22,%20%22gender%22:%20%22female%22,%20%22company%22:%20%22ACCUPHARM%22,%20%22email%22:%20%22bobbibarr@accupharm.com%22,%20%22phone%22:%20%22%2B1%20(938)%20592-3835%22,%20%22address%22:%20%22551%20Lester%20Court,%20Sedley,%20South%20Carolina,%203698%22,%20%22about%22:%20%22Dolor%20deserunt%20nostrud%20ipsum%20sunt%20aute%20elit%20exercitation%20tempor%20eu%20ipsum.%20Dolor%20magna%20nisi%20incididunt%20sit%20non%20mollit%20ut%20aliqua.%20Magna%20est%20officia%20veniam%20sit%20deserunt%20eiusmod%20consectetur%20do%20dolore%20et%20ea%20aliquip.%20Magna%20velit%20tempor%20est%20dolore%20sint%20voluptate.%20Et%20enim%20cillum%20voluptate%20nisi%20est%20non.%20Non%20enim%20amet%20ad%20qui%20cillum%20ipsum%20ipsum%20magna%20id%20nostrud%20cillum%20amet%20esse.%5Cr%5Cn%22,%20%22registered%22:%20%222014-08-05T12:07:38%20%2B07:00%22,%20%22latitude%22:%20-79.673386,%20%22longitude%22:%20-30.821609,%20%22tags%22:%20%5B%20%22aute%22,%20%22consequat%22,%20%22veniam%22,%20%22exercitation%22,%20%22quis%22,%20%22proident%22,%20%22mollit%22%20%5D,%20%22friends%22:%20%5B%20%7B%20%22id%22:%200,%20%22name%22:%20%22Carolina%20Barton%22%20%7D,%20%7B%20%22id%22:%201,%20%22name%22:%20%22Glover%20Gibbs%22%20%7D,%20%7B%20%22id%22:%202,%20%22name%22:%20%22Simpson%20Hicks%22%20%7D%20%5D,%20%22greeting%22:%20%22Hello,%20Bobbi%20Barr!%20You%20have%202%20unread%20messages.%22,%20%22favoriteFruit%22:%20%22banana%22%20%7D%20%5D
2017-02-21 09:28:18.002  INFO 51360 --- [o-auto-1-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-02-21 09:28:18.002  INFO 51360 --- [o-auto-1-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2017-02-21 09:28:18.013  INFO 51360 --- [o-auto-1-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 11 ms
resBody: %5B%20%7B%20%22_id%22:%20%2258ac70a1d998ec63dc004158%22,%20%22index%22:%200,%20%22guid%22:%20%2268124ce4-6a65-4459-8189-f245236399a9%22,%20%22isActive%22:%20true,%20%22balance%22:%20%22$3,415.67%22,%20%22picture%22:%20%22http://placehold.it/32x32%22,%20%22age%22:%2036,%20%22eyeColor%22:%20%22brown%22,%20%22name%22:%20%22Bobbi%20Barr%22,%20%22gender%22:%20%22female%22,%20%22company%22:%20%22ACCUPHARM%22,%20%22email%22:%20%22bobbibarr@accupharm.com%22,%20%22phone%22:%20%22%2B1%20(938)%20592-3835%22,%20%22address%22:%20%22551%20Lester%20Court,%20Sedley,%20South%20Carolina,%203698%22,%20%22about%22:%20%22Dolor%20deserunt%20nostrud%20ipsum%20sunt%20aute%20elit%20exercitation%20tempor%20eu%20ipsum.%20Dolor%20magna%20nisi%20incididunt%20sit%20non%20mollit%20ut%20aliqua.%20Magna%20est%20officia%20veniam%20sit%20deserunt%20eiusmod%20consectetur%20do%20dolore%20et%20ea%20aliquip.%20Magna%20velit%20tempor%20est%20dolore%20sint%20voluptate.%20Et%20enim%20cillum%20voluptate%20nisi%20est%20non.%20Non%20enim%20amet%20ad%20qui%20cillum%20ipsum%20ipsum%20magna%20id%20nostrud%20cillum%20amet%20esse.%5Cr%5Cn%22,%20%22registered%22:%20%222014-08-05T12:07:38%20%2B07:00%22,%20%22latitude%22:%20-79.673386,%20%22longitude%22:%20-30.821609,%20%22tags%22:%20%5B%20%22aute%22,%20%22consequat%22,%20%22veniam%22,%20%22exercitation%22,%20%22quis%22,%20%22proident%22,%20%22mollit%22%20%5D,%20%22friends%22:%20%5B%20%7B%20%22id%22:%200,%20%22name%22:%20%22Carolina%20Barton%22%20%7D,%20%7B%20%22id%22:%201,%20%22name%22:%20%22Glover%20Gibbs%22%20%7D,%20%7B%20%22id%22:%202,%20%22name%22:%20%22Simpson%20Hicks%22%20%7D%20%5D,%20%22greeting%22:%20%22Hello,%20Bobbi%20Barr!%20You%20have%202%20unread%20messages.%22,%20%22favoriteFruit%22:%20%22banana%22%20%7D%20%5D
```

Any idea what's up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hitting [this bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8163#event-946444034). You can avoid the problem by calling TestRestTemplate with a String rather than a URI.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I changed my code to use String uri = ...toUriString() but still have the same issue.
Looks like the fix will be released on March 2nd so I might just wait for that ^^

Comment: You might have a different problem then. Please try using 1.5.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT from https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot and check that problem is fixed.

Comment: 1.5.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT: works with URI; works with string too when I don't call encode() on the UriComponentsBuilder.
1.5.1.RELEASE also works with string when I don't invoke encode() before toUriString... I suppose TestRestTemplate encodes the string url internally... i think it'd be best to let the caller determine whether or not the URI/URL should be encoded and not do extra encoding in TestRestTemplate...